# Versioned view does not reflect the delta changes

Tags: arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-spatial, versioning

I am adding some data using session manager to layer, and saving them. Those changes are visible in delta table in SDE also. But, when I query to count the base table and versioned view result count, it is same as base table.

I want the **base table will give actual count**, and **versioned view = basetable + delta changes**

Using ArcMap 10.6.1, and Oracle as database.

Comment: Your changes will not be migrated from the delta table until you post and reconcile the versioned layer to base. Once you have done that, the base table should show the right number of features.

Comment: Is this data specific?

Comment: @Yogi No, I don't think it is data specific issue. it is related to Arcmap/FM

Comment: Are you running `EXEC sde.set_current_version 'version-session-name';` and then your query?

Comment: @RomaH yes, I tried this query also, and didn't found answer

Comment: @RomaH it is working, actually I was using this earlier also but, I was passing wrong version name. because of which I am not able to fetch the expected result.

Comment: Great! I am glad to hear you figured it out! Be sure to answer your own question, you never know if someone else might have a similar issue.